# Make a variable persist after a restart of NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a message object and it dissapears after **nodejs** restart. How can I make it persist over restarts?
I really don't want to delve into databases and have additional libraries in the project,
only to make it persist over restarts. I think about storing the object into a file, but after trials I'm unable to figure.

I've tried to save the message object variable to file by using `fs` and `JSON`.

```
        newmsg = await message.channel.sendMessage("world");

        const fs = require('fs')
        const data = await JSON.stringify(newmsg)

        // write JSON string to a file
        fs.writeFile('msg.json', data, err => {
          if (err) {
            throw err
          }
          console.log('JSON data is saved.')
        })
```

What I've got instead is an error of

```
(node:430541) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Client'
    |     property '_events' -> object with constructor 'Events'
    |     property 'packet' -> object with constructor 'EE'
    --- property 'context' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/root/bot.js:166:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

At this point I'm not sure how to approach saving this circular structure to a file and then restoring it on the next nodejs relaunch. After researching for quite a while this seems to be complex issue that I still do not understand.

Comment: You could put it in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: The error tells you exactly the problem: The `newmsg` structure is _circular_ and therefor cannot be converted to a `String` via `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Pete I think the OP does not work in a browser environment, meaning there is no localstorage or sessionstorage.

Comment: @user3789797 you can't "just" serialize non-json structures (including circulars, classes, Dates, Events, Client class, etc)